# How to use attribute mapping with EF Core DB First

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I've generated my DbContext using Scaffold-DbContext from existing database.

It uses Fluent mapping API. Is it possible to scaffold the entities so that they are annotated with mapping attributes, e.g.:

```
[Table("People")]
public class Person
{
   [Column("ID")]
   public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use **Scaffold-DbContext** command `-DataAnnotations` switch:

> Use attributes to configure the model (where possible). If omitted, only the fluent API is used.

For more info, see [Command Line Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell).

Comment: It still generates some mapping using fuent api, e.g. indexes, foreign keys, etc

Comment: Well, as you can see, the documentation says **where possible** :) For instance, currently [Indexes can not be created using data annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes). And for FKs you can't control cascade behavior with data annotations. In general fluent configuration is the preferred EFC approach because you can do more things than with data annotations. And I don't think that will change (soon).